# enable button when the save finish successful

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use the following code for edit operation and I've button in the edit screen which I want that it will be enabled when the edit is success

how can I do that?

This is the edit operation

```
 // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="UserId,FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,PhoneWork,WorkingAt")] User user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
            return View(user);
        }
```

This is the button

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("check", "User"))
{
    <input type="submit" id="btn" value="check" />
    <span id='result'></span>
}
```

Comment: U Can use jquery for this purpose...

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to do. That button already looks enabled to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure your use button tag with type submit

```
<button type="submit" id="btn" value="check">Save</button>
```

This is what i m doing for my buttons, just use javascript to achieve.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('invalid-form.validate', 'form', function () {
            var button = $(this).find('button[type="submit"]');
            setTimeout(function () {
                button.removeAttr('disabled');
            }, 1);
        });
        $(document).on('submit', 'form', function () {
            var button = $(this).find('button[type="submit"]');
            setTimeout(function () {
                button.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }, 0);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: thanks but not sure how does it know that the operation was successes ?

Comment: your answer is in  "setTimeout"

Comment: once the post back is done, it will reset its property.

Comment: Thanks a lot voted up,I have currently two button on for save and one for check  when the save button is success (action is success I need to disable the save button and enbable the check button how should I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

First You have to disable your button on load

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("check", "User"))   
{  
   <input type="submit" id="btn" value="check" disabled />
   <span id='result'></span>
}
```

and on your edit button write function onclick=enable(); add jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function enable() {
        var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
        btn.disabled = false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but how the button know that the update process was finish OK?

Comment: set flag after your edit operation perform.And in your jquery use it as condition.if true then enable button.